# Recursive trigger handling

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have the below data in a table

```
  DEPT       ID      ICCODE     OTHER FIELDS
  ====       ===     =====      ============
   10         2        FA         Data1
   20         2        FA         Data2
   30         2        FA         Data3
```

Each department belongs to some external application . If any external application changes ICCODE for  any department I should update the other two departments ICCODE with the same value .

I am writing a trigger on column ICCODE and updating the other two records , but here the problem is the trigger is on the same column and in the trigger modifying the same column values again for different rows . It is causing deadlock situation . Could any one please let me know the solution for this or any workarounds ?  I can not change the structure of the above table , but can create new ones if required . The problem here is the external apps only updates this table ...

Regards

Comment: What does your current trigger look like? Are you actually getting a deadlock, or a mutating table error, which is very different?

Comment: Getting deadlock . Initially got mutating table error and then I used pragma autonomous_transaction; to fix it and got the deadlock error .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data model is a problem because it ought to be normalised as Rene suggested. However, given that you can't do that, and since part of your problem was already a mutating table error (from a comment); **and** assuming you're on 11g or highers, you could solve both problems with a compound trigger.

This is one of the methods for avoiding the mutating table error, as it allows you to maintain a list of affected rows which is build at row level, and then use that collection later at statement level.

This idea just modifies that a bit to also keep track of whether you are hitting the trigger the second time in your statement level trigger, which you can use to avoid recursion:

Let's start with a dummy table and data first:

```
create table t42 (DEPT number, ID number, ICCODE varchar2(2), OTHER_FIELDS varchar2(10));

insert into t42 (dept, id, iccode, other_fields) values (10, 1, 'FA', 'Data1');
insert into t42 (dept, id, iccode, other_fields) values (20, 2, 'FA', 'Data2');
insert into t42 (dept, id, iccode, other_fields) values (30, 3, 'FA', 'Data3');
insert into t42 (dept, id, iccode, other_fields) values (40, 4, 'XY', 'Data4');
```

Without a trigger, updating one row like:

```
update t42 set iccode = 'AF' where id = 1;
```

will only set that single row's value to AF. With a compound trigger that manipulates a collection you could update from the after-statement trigger, but that would be called recursively.

So this uses `dbms_application_info` (or some other mechanism) to see whether the update came from the trigger itself, or from somewhere else:

```
create or replace trigger test_trigger
for update of iccode on t42
compound trigger

  -- collection to hold old and new values
  type t_changed_row is record (old_value t42.iccode%type, new_value t42.iccode%type);
  type t_changed_rows is table of t_changed_row;
  l_changed_rows t_changed_rows := t_changed_rows();

  l_fixed_info constant varchar2(30) := 'compound trigger hack';

  after each row is
    l_info varchar2(30);
  begin
    dbms_application_info.read_client_info(l_info);
    if l_info is null or l_info != l_fixed_info then
      -- not in nested update; store old and new values
      l_changed_rows.extend;
      l_changed_rows(l_changed_rows.count).old_value := :old.iccode;
      l_changed_rows(l_changed_rows.count).new_value := :new.iccode;
    end if;
  end after each row;

  after statement is
    l_old_info varchar2(30);
  begin
    -- could check current value here as well but may not be worth it;
    -- the collection will be empty anyway on second-level hit

    -- store existing value to restore later
    dbms_application_info.read_client_info(l_old_info);

    -- set info to block recursion  
    dbms_application_info.set_client_info(l_fixed_info);

    -- update table based on all old/new value pairs at once
    forall i in 1..l_changed_rows.count
      update t42
      set iccode = l_changed_rows(i).new_value
      where iccode = l_changed_rows(i).old_value;

    -- reset info
    dbms_application_info.set_client_info(l_old_info);
  end after statement;

end test_trigger;
/
```

And this now updates all of the matching values:

```
update t42 set iccode = 'AF' where id = 1;

1 row updated.

select * from t42;

      DEPT         ID IC OTHER_FIEL
---------- ---------- -- ----------
        10          1 AF Data1     
        20          2 AF Data2     
        30          3 AF Data3     
        40          4 XY Data4
```

All of the FA values have been changed to AF, despite only one row apparently being updated.

Fixing the data model would still be much better, but this kind of approach might do as a workaround given your restrictions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution . I was not knowing about compound triggers . Before getting the solution what I did was 1) Created a trigger on the table and inserted data into temporary table 2) Created a scheduler that listens for every second on this temporary table and sees if there are any new records 3) If there are new records it updates the main table with the values ( Even in this case it raises a trigger again , but I have condition put in the query to check on dummy table to see if it is already processed record or not . If it is not it gets processed otherwise it gets ignored .

Answer (score 0):

You should create a table with an ID column and a CODE column and store your ICCODE in that table

```
ID ICCODE
== ====
 1 FA
```

Change your table so that it holds the ID of the ICCODE table instead of the code itself.

```
  DEPT       ID      IC_ID     OTHER FIELDS
  ====       ===     =====      ============
   10         2        1         Data1
   20         2        1         Data2
   30         2        1         Data3
```

If needed update the code in the ICCODE table.

Lookup the ICCODE when querying your table.

Comment: I am sorry I don't have control on the existing table . I can create new tables , but can't make changes to the existing table .